# What does hbase returns when get is called for either row key, Column Family , Column Qualifier

Tags: hbase

What does hbase returns when get is called for either row key, Column Family , Column Qualifier

1. When Called with `get ( ROW_KEY1 )` what does it returns, does it returns all the `CFs` and then respective `CQs`
2. When Called with `get ( ROW_KEY, CF)` does it returns all the `CQs` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), it will return all the column families and column qualifiers. 
For (2), it will return all the column qualifiers for the specified column family.